# Unable to find a button element when crawling website

Tags: selenium-webdriver, button, xpath, scrapy, web-crawler

I am trying to build a code on Python using the Scrapy library that logs into the Glassdoor website, searches for and selects a company (Google in this case), and applies filters to the company's reviews based on the location (Switzerland - All Cities in this case). The spider uses the Selenium library to automate browser actions, such as clicking buttons and inputting text.

I have noticed, that the code runs always to different stages, which really confuses me. Further the crawler is not able to identify and click the "filter" I have created in the code.

My code looks as followed:

```
[...]
class GetdataSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'getdata'
    allowed_domains = ['www.glassdoor.com']
    start_urls = ['http://www.glassdoor.com/']
    # company_list = ["Google","KPMG","Roland Berger","Accenture","McKinsey & Company"]
    # location_list = ["Switzerland - All Cities","United States - All Cities","Sweden, ME","Norway - All Cities"]

    #username = 'username'
    #password = 'password'

    def parse(self, response):
        url = 'https://www.glassdoor.com/profile/login_input.htm'
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome('C:\DRIVERS\chromedriver.exe')
        self.driver.get(url)
        sleep(2)
        
        username = self.driver.find_element("id",'inlineUserEmail')
        sleep(1)
        username.send_keys('user@name.de')
        sleep(1)
        button = self.driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="InlineLoginModule"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/button/span').click()
        sleep(1)

        password = self.driver.find_element("id",'inlineUserPassword')
        sleep(2)
        password.send_keys('password')
        sleep(1)
        cookies = self.driver.find_element  ("xpath", '//*[@id="onetrust-accept-btn-handler"]').click()
        button2 = self.driver.find_element("xpath",'//*[@id="InlineLoginModule"]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/div/form/div[2]/button').click()
        print("Login erfolgreich")
        sleep(2)
        
        insert_company = self.driver.find_element("id",'sc.keyword')
        insert_company.click()
        sleep(5)
        insert_company.send_keys('Google')
        sleep(5)
        insert_company.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        sleep(3)
        #click on company
        transfer = self.driver.find_element("xpath", "//a[@class='company-tile d-flex flex-column flex-sm-row align-items-start p-std mb-sm-std css-poeuz4 css-1wh1oc8'][1]")
        transfer.click()
        sleep(5)
        #click on reviews 
        #reviews = self.driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id='EmpLinksWrapper']/div[2]/div/div[1]/a[1]/p")
        reviews = self.driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id='EmpLinksWrapper']/div[2]/div/div[1]/a[1]")
        reviews.click()
        sleep(3)
```

Most of the time the code runs until here, but again sometimes it stucks somewhere...
Then there is the filter issue:

```
#select filter
        Filter = self.driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id='Container']/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[2]/div[2]/button")
        Filter.click()
        sleep(3)
        #install filter
        location = self.driver.find_element("xpath","//*[@id='Container']/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div")
        self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", location)
        #location = WebDriverWait(self.driver, 10).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located(("xpath","//*[@id='Container']/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div/input")))
        #WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable(("xpath","//*[@id='Container']/div[1]/div[2]/main/div[1]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div")))
        location.send_keys('Switzerland - All Cities')
        sleep(2)
        #location.send_keys('Switzerland - All Cities')
        #sleep(2)
        location.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)
        sleep(5)
        [...]
```

The crawler simply gets stuck and shuts down.

The settings file looks as follows (if needed):

```
BOT_NAME = 'glassdoor_crawl'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['glassdoor_crawl.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'glassdoor_crawl.spiders'

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True
HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES =[403]
DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.useragent.UserAgentMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry.RetryMiddleware': None,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RandomUserAgentMiddleware': 400,
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.middleware.RetryUserAgentMiddleware': 401,
}

FAKEUSERAGENT_PROVIDERS = [
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakeUserAgentProvider',  # This is the first provider we'll try
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FakerProvider',  # If FakeUserAgentProvider fails, we'll use faker to generate a user-agent string for us
    'scrapy_fake_useragent.providers.FixedUserAgentProvider',  # Fall back to USER_AGENT value
]

# Set Fallback User-Agent
USER_AGENT = 'Mozilla/5.0 (iPad; CPU OS 12_2 like Mac OS X) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Mobile/15E148'
```

I tried to check and change the x-path of the filter button, but unfortunately was unable to reach it with the code. I also tried the

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("xx")
```

but it seemed not to match the code